# How to handle front end in Lumen

Tags: lumen

I want to build an app using Vuejs and Lumen. I know that Lumen is for API (to serve JSON) only and from version 5.2 they removed View from Lumen.

Now I don't know how to place my HTML (with VUEJS code) to consume JSON from Lumen. Of course I can have separate app/project for front end but that's not seem right, as I have to maintain two separate projects.

Can I return HTML page in home page ('/'), and every action since then will be serve via Json API? How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling without any answer, I reviewed some projects on Github and found out that latest version as of now (5.2.7) supported `view` back.